# WiFi and collisions

Tags: wireless, wifi, network, mac

since all WiFi operates in the same frequency which is 2.4 GHZ , if we set a certain number of access points in the same Region , for example , the maximum distance between them is 15 meters , could this cause to interference between signals , and also we can not connect to the network , because :

1. the interference between the signals.
2. the collisions between the packets that can be transmitt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should remember that channels 1,5,11 (or 1,6,13 in europe) do not overlap,
so set your APs each to one channel in this list. There will be no interference or collisions this way, unless you have more than 3 AP/routers in the same area.

Note that this applies to 20 MHz channels - newer Wifi ("N" standard) supports 40 Mhz channel width, this should be disabled in your case.

Comment: I have conclude from the other answer , that this can be avoided even we use a near channel if we use a certain technique ?

Answer (score 1):

Co channel interference will increase likelihood of collision during Direct Sequence FM  in channel, but this more tolerant than other methods of spectrum spreading.  Collisions can be avoided by DS coding of FM to spread spectrum, or frequency hopping in BT or TDM in slotted ALOHA.   So yes it may interfere, but low probability for only a few sources. Modulation Details required for mathematical calculations on collision rates.

•Self-interference should be Gaussian
•Based on Viterbi’s argument, this represents a saddle (not optimal) point.
•If the self-interference is treated as noise, not interference,  then Gaussian signaling is suboptimal (by Shannon theory).

**spread spectrum lost out to OFDM in 4G**

For practical concerns in home Wifi, I get more deadzones from Rician Fading (self interference) using N speeds than using G and even more reliable with B, which I discovered recently using new ASUS on N speeds of 100Mb for playing recorded TV uncompressed from server wifi router upstairs while laptop in basement.
The deadspots show like interference patterns of waves on water where the intersecting phase cancellation is periodic , thus when video stopped and started to buffer, I just had to nudge the laptop a cm or two to get out of the null spot and work with the 4 bar signal which had strong reflections.  Although this is self interference, it can be degraded with strong cochannel signals , so if performance is poor and not from a dead spot, I switch router to a different channel or band type N to G or worst case to B only in fringe area outside. You can also force mobile to limited maximum speeds N, G or B in fringe wifi areas.

Comment: Wifi has fixed channels and no frequency hopping. You may have mixed this up with bluetooth.